# shadow-box in different browsers

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-tables, shadowbox

Shadow table cells displayed in different browsers differently. Here's the code itself. How to do that would display the same?

```
box-shadow: 2px -2px 6px #000000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px -2px 6px #000000;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/unma777w/3/

Comment: you don't need vendor prefixes for ``box-shadow`` anymore.

Comment: I removed the prefix, the result remained the same. In mozilla shadow-box displayed correctly in chrome no http://jsfiddle.net/unma777w/5/

Answer (score 0):

box-shadow (without prefix) is largely supported by all browsers without too much concern (with the exception of IE8 and before).
About the cross browser differences of rendering: i wouldn't concern too much.
You can anyway try to add the vendor's prefix as first choice and check if stuation improves... you can't do much more than this.